# Adding images to phpword with cloneblock

Tags: php, mysql, phpword

Please assist me. See code below. I  am adding data to my phpword document, using a template processor, and creating a new document. I have just resolved the adding text issue, as the data in the clone block was being duplicated throughout. But now I am having the same issue with images.

My observations.

1. My file path is media\123456789.jpg (as an example), but I notice to troubleshoot I instead said setvalue instead of setimage, to see if it gets the file name correct. But it adds media3456789.jpg. So it leaves out the backslash and the following 2 characters. But I don't think this is the root cause. My point below describes why.
2. It adds the first clone block/ loop interaction images fine.....so I don't think the file name is a problem....by the way. If I setvalue the file name, it displays the correct name in the word document, although the name is truncated, the ending of the file name is correct, so why question why isn't it populating the block with the correct image instead of duplicating the first set of images.

   ```
   $group_key=1;

   do {
       //echo "";

       $repeatgroup = $id."/"."trailer_repeat_group"."[".$group_key."]";

       //echo "repeatgroup before query___ ".$repeatgroup;

       //echo "";

       // inserting data from trailer table

       $trailer_repeat_grouping = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM trailer_repeat_group LEFT JOIN odkmain on trailer_repeat_group.PARENT_KEY = odkmain.metainstanceID WHERE trailer_repeat_group.KEY_id = '$repeatgroup'");

       $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('CLONEME', $trailer_count);

       while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($trailer_repeat_grouping))
       {
           $templateProcessor->setValue("Left_trailer_tyre_condition",$row1['Left_trailer_tyre_condition'],2);

           $templateProcessor->insertImage("img:right_handtrailer_tyres_image",$row1['right_handtrailer_tyres_image'],2);

           $templateProcessor->setValue("right_trailer_tyre_condition",$row1['right_trailer_tyre_condition'],2);

           $templateProcessor->insertImage("img:left_handtrailer_tyres_image",$row1['left_handtrailer_tyres_image'],2);

       }

       //echo mysqli_num_rows($trailer_repeat_grouping);

       //    endwhile;

       $group_key++;

   } while ($group_key <= $trailer_count)
   ```

Comment: how about inserting images before than doing setvalue ?

Comment: @num8er Hi. I've just tried that. Still seems to duplicate the first block.

Comment: how about doing `cloneBlock` once inside while loop? `while(...) { cloneBlock('CLONEME', 1);; insertImage; setValue; }` - idea is that make a single clone and replace content in place, then clone another and replace too

Comment: @num8er Hi. Have tried that now. Still doesn't loop and insert second clone group, it's still duplicating first block in the second block. Text(set value ) works fine and populates second block correctly strangely enough.

Comment: I just want to clarify something, apart from the opening and closing clone block tags in my word doc, does anything else needs to be done in my word doc to actually action the above so maybe for the images to insert properly ?